# How could I print the table on the left of the page

Tags: tables, exam

I want to make a math exam paper via exam package but with the information of students on the left of the first page. We may deal with this by rotated line. However, it is the table I have to print. By the way, there is some error if I use table enviorment in the minipage enviorment.
This is what I supposed to achieve by office.
[image]

Here is the  code without the exam package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [xshift=2cm,yshift=-1.5cm] at (current page.north west) (topleft){};
\node [xshift=2cm,yshift=1.5cm] at (current page.south west) (bottomleft){};
\draw [->] (topleft.south) -- (bottomleft.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{mytable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
name\\
\hline
\\
\hline
id\\
\hline
\\
\hline
subject\\
\hline
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would remove the `\centering` command and and load the  `caption` package for *not* centring the caption, with `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}`

Comment: I add the `caption` table and delete `\centering` command, but the table is still on the right of the vertical line.

Comment: Why have you put a \newpage inside a table? What is the line for?

Comment: Soooorry, it's a typo.

Comment: Can you make a rough drawing of what you want and upload the picture?

Comment: @S.Venkataraman I edit my ques.

Comment: I just found that we could do this by using tikz again instead of table environment.

Comment: There is also \marginpar (possibly \reversemarginpar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use standard `exam` methods, hooking into `\lhead`: the left header will contain `\databox`, whose duty is to typeset the data box having zero width and height, but with parameters to place it down the left margin. Then `\databox` redefines itself to do nothing.

```latex
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\databox}{%
  \smash{\makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\[2in] % lower the box
    \hline
    name\\
    \hline
    \\[2\normalbaselineskip]
    \hline
    id\\
    \hline
    \\[1.5\normalbaselineskip]
    \hline
    subject\\
    \hline
    \\[3\normalbaselineskip]
    \hline
    \end{tabular}\quad
  }}%
  \gdef\databox{}%
}

\lhead{\databox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to move the table toward right a little bit but with the text on the right motionless. And I may concern whether the table will cover the text.

Comment: @Brooks Change `\quad` into `\hspace{...}` until you're satisfied. Tthe argument should be a length; as long as it's positive, the table will stay in the margin.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you set up two `minipage` environments, a narrow one on the left, a wide one on the right. As long as the contents of the minipages fit within the overall page, they will be centered vertically relative to each other. In the example below, the ratio of minipage widths is set to 3:17; obviously, you're free to choose a different ratio.

Then, in the left-hand `minipage`, use a single-column `tabularx` environment. Since it doesn't look like you need to set a `\caption`, I don't think there's a purpose in employing a `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{4} % or some other suitable factor
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{}C@{}|}
\hline
Name\\    \hline
{}\\      \hline
id\\      \hline
{}\\      \hline
subject\\ \hline
{}\\      \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr0.85\textwidth-1em\relax}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer. there is a new problem, I have to decide where to creat a new page in the right minipage.

Comment: @Brooks - Please provide more information about your additional typographic objective.

Comment: The length of the stuff in the right minipage is due to some math exercise, but different kinds of exercise have different size. I don't know there is how many questions on the first page.

Comment: @Brooks - And what would "different sizes" be?

Comment: @Brooks -- Are you maybe asking how to center the two-minipage block vertically on a page?

Comment: no. Suppose it is `\lipsum[1-7]`.

Comment: @Brooks - As I was careful to note in my answer, it applied to cases where the text material actually fits on a page.

Comment: thanks, I missed the words before.